# how to await setState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am dynamically adding item to `ListView`. When I add new item, it should scroll to bottom like in WhatsApp app.

I am doing it like this

```
setState(() {
  _textList.add(text);
});
_scrollController.animateTo( //Should run after rebuild
  _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

Since `setState()` runs asynchronously, `maxScrollExtent` is not updated, which is resulting in scroll until previous item only.

How to do `await` for `setState`. Is there anyway to achieve this. Also I don't want do call `Future.delayed`.

Here is my full code [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e590aae93ef24b30bfb5cd2c37d25b2c).

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273797/8112679

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/43370176/using-async-setstate

Comment: @Salma. that link is related to reactjs :(

Comment: use scrollcontroller not set state to dynamically scroll to positions. what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916247/flutter-scroll-to-bottom-of-dynamic-listview ?

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance..addPostFrameCallback` is what I actually wanted like @HarshvardhanJoshi mentioned.  But there is a new problem by using it, I am trying to solve it. Thanks @Salma.

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica Ok I changed my question title.

Comment: SetState is synchronous, so the whole question doesn't make sense

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat what problem are you facing?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi If I add `_scrollController.animateTo` as call back in `addPostFrameCallback`, it scrolls once. But my `ListView` is lazily build.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Important: I only want it to scroll to bottom when i send message, not when receive message. So I did not  use it inside `build`

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat you should use this code when sending message. As in somewhere where you trigger an event for sending message. Like, side onTap of the send button

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi that is what I did. The problem is solved. Because of the debug mode, it looked like jumping around. It works good in performance mode. Thank you so much

Comment: Don't do close vote with another post that is not even related to this topic. At least see the tags attached

Comment: @RémiRousselet Atleast some people understood the problem and gave the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method as the first line in your build method.

```
         WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
                    _scrollController.animateTo( 
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  });
```